# Is there a way to return a substring of a string using Convolutional Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm a PhD student in genetics and molecular biology working on an algorithm to identify if a DNA sequence is either a transposable element (TE) or not a TE using convolutional neural networks, and it's already working kind of the way I'd like it to (of course I'm always trying to improve it).

The input is a [FASTA file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) containing multiple DNA sequences. The algorithm analyses each sequence and returns if it is or not a TE, but here is the thing: not necessarily the whole sequence is a TE; in many cases, just a fragment (like a sub-string of the string) is a TE.

I'd like to know if there is a way to map the coordinates and/or return the fragment representing the TE. For me it seems kinda tricky because of all the sequence pre-processing of one hot encoding, flattening etc, and I don't know how the sequences of zeros and ones that the original became can return me what I want. Although I know some python and I'm studying machine learning and deep learning to know how it works, my area is biological sciences not computer science or something related.

Here I'll try to exemplify the described above.

Let's say I have these three sequences, the sub-string in lower case (just for the sake of the example, it'll not be like this) is the TE.

```
>NAD4
TAATATTAAGATaggattgggattgtatgaagggttaaaattaatatttctataatattaatagaaaaaaagttgttaagatttttatttacgaagccatgttgagttcttCCAAAAA
>NAD4-V
CTAGTTAAAAGTAAATGTTaagataaggattgggattgtatgaagggttaaaattaatatttctataatattaatagaaaaaaagttgttAAGATTTTTATTTACGAAGCCATGTTGAG
>STL-M
TCGAAGAAGGGGTCATTAAATTTACTTTTGCTTTTTATACTATATTAGATCTTAAATCGTTTATATGTTTTTTTTAAAAAAACTATAAAGTTACCCACAAATAGAAAATTTGTTGTGCT
```

I'd like to have something like the following as the output:

```
ID  Classification  Coordinates Sequence
NAD4       TE          13:112   aggattgggattgtatgaagggttaaaattaatatttctataatattaatagaaaaaaagttgttaagatttttatttacgaagccatgttgagttctt
NAD4-V     TE          20:91    aagataaggattgggattgtatgaagggttaaaattaatatttctataatattaatagaaaaaaagttgtt
STL-M      NT          NaN      NaN
```

Am I asking too much from the neural network and I'll have to use some tool/custom script after the prediction to figure out the sequences and/or coordinates?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you currently have a NN which outputs some probability that a given DNA sequence is a TE?

Comment: Do you have limits on the lengths of your sequences?

Comment: Exactly. Yes I have, maximum lenght is about 19000 nucleotides.

Comment: What's the minimum?

Comment: I guess it is 4 nucleotides, because sequences must have at least one 'A', one 'C', one 'G' and one 'T'.

Comment: How exact do you need to be with identifying the beginning/end? Can you be off by 100bps? 10% of the sequence? &c?

Comment: Do you mean like a margin of error? Well, for sure the more precise the best, but something like 5-10 nucleotides (nt) before the beginning, 5-10 after the end may be acceptable in a 100 nt sequence.

Comment: Is the TE a known string? Or are you hoping to do some loose matching?

Comment: No, it's not. My goal is to identify new possible TE's in a genome. In some cases, correct misclassified sequences, like, check if sequences classified as TE's by other tools really are TE's and also the opposite.

Comment: I think I have no idea what the exact problem formulation is. You might be better off on this forum if you just tried to state everything in terms of strings, stripping all of the language from genetics out of the formulation.

Comment: Like, I'm trying to evaluate if some strings are from a certain class; If, a string is classified by the NN with label '1' (TE) for instance, then I'd like to check if it's the whole string or if it's just a sub-string (or sub-stringS) inside this string. If so, then I'd like to know the position of the substring inside the string and return this substring. (if this explanation is good enough I can edit my post and add there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with a disclaimer, my PhD is in the fast computation of eigenvalues, my specialty is not in machine learning at all. This is just some stuff I remember from some master level courses. I have two ideas that might work.

**Idea 1**

Traditional convolutional neural nets are very good at classifying. For example, "does this image contain a dog", or in your case "does this sequence contain a TE". The reason for this is translational invariance. That's a fancy term to say that these nets, by their convolutional nature, tend not to care where something is in an image or sequence, only what it is. This makes them way better at generalizing.

When people started to use convolutional neural nets to find out where something is in an image, not just whether it is present, they had to change the architecture of the neural net. Those neural nets use branches of fully connected layers and convolutional layers and reconnect them later to recover the information about the location. You could do something similar to recover the location of the TE sequence.

Depending on your luck you might be able to use the object localization networks that other people have designed for your use cases.

**Idea 2**

When dealing with sequences, recurrent neural networks (RNN) usually work quite well. Instead of dealing with the entire sequence at once, they take in token by token and as such can provide information about the location. The natural language processing researchers have had a lot of success using these networks, but they are quite sensitive to the training in my experience, YMMV.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you I'll try something based on your ideas! Just one more thing, Do you think LSTM would be a good idea? I've been thinking about trying to use it.

Comment: Yes, especially when it requires deep connections, LSTM should perform a lot better.

Comment: Hi! I've created a LSTM model based on what we've talked here, but I still haven't found a way to return the substrings in prediction. Is there a way to to this? or will I just be able to return the class in the prediction output?

Comment: This is related to image classification v.s. object localization. For convolutional networks, this is solved by reconnecting the layers in a special way. For recurrent networks, you could look at the intermediate outputs of the network (although i have no experience with that).

Comment: Good to hear that you got your classifier working (kind of)

Comment: Understood. Thank you again for the help!